# Marking a pair of @ManyToOne related properties as unique. Possible?

Tags: java, jpa, playframework-2.0, playframework-1.x

I have the typical example, where a POST has many TAGS, and a TAG has many POSTs.
Instead of using a typical `@ManyToMany`, I use a domain object in the middle, called TAGPOST, which also allows me to have useful data in there, such as when a post was tagged with a given tag, etc. Each POST, and TAG resp, is in a `@OneToMany` relationship with a TAGPOST.

The specific requirement is that a post cannot have the same tag included twice, therefore the TAGPOST.post and TAGPOST.tag pair must always be unique. Normally, I would do that by making a  composite primary key pair in the table, responsible for storing TAGPOST objects.

AFAIK, there is no way to express this unique constraint. I have marked `jpa.ddl=update`, which means that every time I move the application to a new environment, I will have to go and manually fix this in the DB. This is very inconvenient, and error prone, especially when unit testing, because then the database is created and dropped more or less in every iteration.

I was even thinking to do the check manually on `@PrePersist`, or even move the check in a business layer, say, create a PostService.

What do I do? Am I missing something that Play has by default? Some clever annotation to express the uniqueness of the `@ManyToOne` properties of the TAGPOST class?

FYI: I am using Play 1.2.5

EDIT: The TAGPOST class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class TagPost extends Model {

    @ManyToOne
    public Tag tag;

    @ManyToOne
    public Post post;

    public Date dateAdded;

    ...
}
```

Comment: I think you can have a composite id for your `TagPost` object. Can you share the code for `TagPost` class?

Comment: @dcernahoschi just posted it

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a custom `Check` for db uniqueness. Maybe you should customize it.

**DBUnique.java**

```
package models.check;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import net.sf.oval.configuration.annotation.Constraint;
import play.db.jpa.GenericModel;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Constraint(checkWith = DbUniqueCheck.class)
public @interface DBUnique {
    String message() default DbUniqueCheck.mes;

    Class<? extends GenericModel> modelClass();

    String field() default ""; // field name will be used
}
```

**DbUniqueCheck.java**

```
package models.check;


import net.sf.oval.Validator;
import net.sf.oval.configuration.annotation.AbstractAnnotationCheck;
import net.sf.oval.context.FieldContext;
import net.sf.oval.context.OValContext;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

import play.db.jpa.GenericModel.JPAQuery;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DbUniqueCheck extends AbstractAnnotationCheck<DBUnique> {

final static String mes = "validation.dbunique";
DBUnique dbUnique;

@Override
public void configure(DBUnique dBUnique) {
    this.dbUnique = dBUnique;
    setMessage(dBUnique.message());
}

public boolean isSatisfied(Object validatedObject, Object value, OValContext context, Validator validator) {
    try {
        String field = dbUnique.field();
        if (field == null || field.isEmpty()) {
            field = ((FieldContext) context).getField().getName();
        }
        JPAQuery q = (JPAQuery) dbUnique.modelClass().getMethod("find", String.class, Object[].class)
                .invoke(null, "by" + StringUtils.capitalize(field), new Object[] { value });
        return q.first() == null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

usage : [link to gist](https://gist.github.com/hgo/5227028)

it simply checks the given `field` for given `class` instance is unique in db. Maybe you should make something like these..

Comment: Never used it before, but there's a way to add unique constraints in the @Table annotation. Maybe that would help ? @Table(uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(...),)

Comment: `@UniqueConstraint` creates a unique constraint on db side. So if you want to persist the modal via JPA, JPA will rise an exception. You should handle the exception. On the other side(with `check`), if you validate the modal, you can get a validation.error. No exception, no trycatches, no rollbacks and db level checks.. [check this out](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/validation)